Unable to change awx custom volumeMount permissions in k3s init container
I am currently trying to edit my AWX deployment on k3s. The goal is to add a PVC as a volume mount so that I have persistent storage to write files to from my Ansible tasks. The PVC mounts to the Task and Web containers per the documentation on extra volumes. However, the init_container_extra_commands is giving me a permissions error when attempting to use chmod 775 && chgrp 1000 on the volumeMount.
I've tried altering the AWX securityContext to run as privileged, run as root, run as the awx uid and guid, change the fsGroup to 1000 (the awx guid). Thus far I haven't been able to get the volume to mount and then have permissions changed.
Below is my AWX.yaml
---
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: awx
spec:
  # These parameters are designed for use with:
  # - AWX Operator: 2.0.0
  #   https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator/blob/2.0.0/README.md
  # - AWX: 22.0.0
  #   https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/22.0.0/INSTALL.md

  admin_user: admin
  admin_password_secret: awx-admin-password

  ingress_type: ingress
  ingress_tls_secret: awx-secret-tls
  hostname: awx.awx.org

  bundle_cacert_secret: awx-custom-certs

  postgres_configuration_secret: awx-postgres-configuration

  postgres_storage_class: awx-postgres-volume
  postgres_storage_requirements:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi

  projects_persistence: true
  projects_existing_claim: awx-projects-claim

  web_replicas: 1
  task_replicas: 1

  postgres_init_container_resource_requirements: {}
  postgres_resource_requirements: {}
  web_resource_requirements: {}
  task_resource_requirements: {}
  ee_resource_requirements: {}
  init_container_resource_requirements: {}

  extra_volumes: |
    - name: cert-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: awx-cert-storage-claim

  task_extra_volume_mounts: |
    - name: cert-storage
      mountPath: /data/cert-storage

  init_container_extra_volume_mounts: |
    - name: cert-storage
      mountPath: /data/cert-storage

  init_container_extra_commands: |
    chmod 775 /data/cert-storage
    chgrp 1000 /data/cert-storage

  # Uncomment to reveal "censored" logs
  no_log: false

